# JavaScript end game, display players highest score and rank players highest score

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a simple JavaScript html game. just question and answer.
The player have just 20 seconds to answer the questions.
The issue I am have is that after the time is up, players are still able to answer questions and the score keeps adding up.

How do i display "Game Over" after time is up.
Also, how do i display their score?

```js
const startButton = document.getElementById('start-btn')
const nextButton = document.getElementById('next-btn')
const questionContainerElement = document.getElementById('question-container')
const questionElement = document.getElementById('question')
const answerButtonsElement = document.getElementById('answer-buttons')

let shuffledQuestions, currentQuestionIndex
let countRightAnswers = 0;

startButton.addEventListener('click', startGame)
nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  currentQuestionIndex++
  setNextQuestion()
}
)
function startGame() {
  startButton.classList.add('hide')
  shuffledQuestions = questions.sort(() => Math.random() - .5)
  currentQuestionIndex = 0
  questionContainerElement.classList.remove('hide')
  countRightAnswers = 0;
  c = 20;
  setNextQuestion()
}

function setNextQuestion() {
  resetState()
  showQuestion(shuffledQuestions[currentQuestionIndex])
}

function showQuestion(question) {
  questionElement.innerText = question.question
  question.answers.forEach(answer => {
    const button = document.createElement('button')
    button.innerText = answer.text
    button.classList.add('btn')
    if (answer.correct) {
      button.dataset.correct = answer.correct
    }
    button.addEventListener('click', selectAnswer)
    answerButtonsElement.appendChild(button)
  })
}

function resetState() {
  clearStatusClass(document.body)
  nextButton.classList.add('hide')
  while (answerButtonsElement.firstChild) {
    answerButtonsElement.removeChild(answerButtonsElement.firstChild)
  }
}

function selectAnswer(e) {
  const selectedButton = e.target
  const correct = selectedButton.dataset.correct
  setStatusClass(document.body, correct)
  Array.from(answerButtonsElement.children).forEach(button => {
    setStatusClass(button, button.dataset.correct)
  })
  if (shuffledQuestions.length > currentQuestionIndex + 1) {
    nextButton.classList.remove('hide')
  } else {
    startButton.innerText = 'Restart'
    startButton.classList.remove('hide')
  }
  if (selectedButton.dataset = correct) {
    countRightAnswers++;
  }
  document.getElementById('score001').innerHTML = countRightAnswers;
}

function setStatusClass(element, correct) {
  clearStatusClass(element)
  if (correct) {
    element.classList.add('correct')
  } else {
    element.classList.add('wrong')
  }
}

function clearStatusClass(element) {
  element.classList.remove('correct')
  element.classList.remove('wrong')
}

function timer001() {
  c = c - 1;
  if (c < 20) {
    time001.innerHTML = c;
  }

  if (c < 1) {
    window.clearInterval(update);
  }
}

update = setInterval('timer001()', 1000);

const questions = [
  {
    question: 'What is 4 + 4?',
    answers: [
      { text: '4', correct: false },
      { text: '22', correct: false },
      { text: '8', correct: true },
      { text: '44', correct: false }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: 'Who is the developer of this game?',
    answers: [
      { text: 'Otis', correct: true },
      { text: 'Jesus', correct: false },
      { text: 'Mike', correct: false },
      { text: 'Jason', correct: false }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: 'What is the middle day of the week?',
    answers: [
      { text: 'Monday', correct: false },
      { text: 'Thursday', correct: true },
      { text: 'Wednesday', correct: false },
      { text: 'Friday', correct: false }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: 'What is the middle day of the work week?',
    answers: [
      { text: 'Monday', correct: false },
      { text: 'Thursday', correct: false },
      { text: 'Wednesday', correct: true },
      { text: 'Friday', correct: false }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: 'Monday, Tuesday, ______, Thursday?',
    answers: [
      { text: 'Monday', correct: false },
      { text: 'Thursday', correct: false },
      { text: 'Wednesday', correct: true },
      { text: 'Friday', correct: false }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: '1, 2, 3, ____, 5',
    answers: [
      { text: '1', correct: false },
      { text: '2', correct: false },
      { text: '4', correct: true },
      { text: '3', correct: false }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: 'What is 2 + 2?',
    answers: [
      { text: '4', correct: true },
      { text: '2', correct: false },
      { text: '22', correct: false },
      { text: '24', correct: false }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: 'May, June, ______?',
    answers: [
      { text: 'May', correct: false },
      { text: 'July', correct: true },
      { text: 'June', correct: false },
      { text: 'April', correct: false }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: 'Untied State of ______',
    answers: [
      { text: 'Washington', correct: false },
      { text: 'New York', correct: false },
      { text: 'America', correct: true },
      { text: 'Maryland', correct: false }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: 'If b=y, and y=3, then b=?',
    answers: [
      { text: '2', correct: false },
      { text: '3', correct: true },
      { text: '4', correct: false },
      { text: '6', correct: false }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: 'If ab=y, and a=4, b=2, then y=?',
    answers: [
      { text: '8', correct: true },
      { text: '6', correct: false },
      { text: '4', correct: false },
      { text: '2', correct: false }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: 'If x=y, and x=0, then y=??',
    answers: [
      { text: '0', correct: true },
      { text: '2', correct: false },
      { text: '4', correct: false },
      { text: '8', correct: false }
    ]
  }
]
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Gotham Rounded;
}

:root {
  --hue-neutral: 200;
  --hue-wrong: 0;
  --hue-correct: 145;
}

body {
  --hue: var(--hue-neutral);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: hsl(var(--hue), 100%, 20%);
}

body.correct {
  --hue: var(--hue-correct);
}

body.wrong {
  --hue: var(--hue-wrong);
}

.container {
  width: 800px;
  max-width: 80%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px;
}

.btn-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  gap: 10px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.btn {
  --hue: var(--hue-neutral);
  border: 1px solid hsl(var(--hue), 100%, 30%);
  background-color: hsl(var(--hue), 100%, 50%);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  border-color: black;
}

.btn.correct {
  --hue: var(--hue-correct);
  color: black;
}

.btn.wrong {
  --hue: var(--hue-wrong);
}

.start-btn,
.next-btn {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.controls {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
    <span id="right-answers"></span>
    <title>Games</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="question-container" class="hide">
        <div id="question">Question</div>
        <text>Score: <text id="score001">0</text></text
        ><br />
        <text>Time: <text id="time001">20</text></text
        ><br />
        <div id="answer-buttons" class="btn-grid">
          <button class="btn">Answer 1</button>
          <button class="btn">Answer 2</button>
          <button class="btn">Answer 3</button>
          <button class="btn">Answer 4</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="controls">
        <button id="start-btn" class="start-btn btn">Start</button>
        <button id="next-btn" class="next-btn btn hide">Next</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you need to focus on is lexical scope or scope, if you set all your timers as variables at the start it will be easy to clear them later. You can also set a variable to hold your score at the top level.
for example
`var timer1 = "";
var score = 0;
function innerScoper() {
//update timer or score
score = 2;
}
function endGame() {
console.log(score)
//clear timeouts
}`

Comment: Hi @gou, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Comment: how do I restart the game, my function is not working. 
html
 <button id="restart-btn" class="restart-btn btn hide">Next</button>

scirpt
const restartButton = document.getElementById('restart-btn')

restartButton.addEventListener('click', restart)
function restart() {
    startGame();
    setNextQuestion();
    resetState();
}

Answer (score 0):

To disable the buttons once the timer is up:

```
function timer001() {
  c = c - 1;
  if (c < 20) {
      time001.innerHTML = c;
  }
 
  if (c < 1) 
  {
    window.clearInterval(update);
    
    // get all of the buttons by class
    let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("btn")
    
    // loop through the array of buttons, set them to be disabled
    for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) 
    {
       buttons[i].disabled = true
    }   
  }
}
```

It looks like your game already displays their score when the game is over, but maybe you could [create a popup](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_popup.asp) to display a "Game Over" screen.

Alternatively, you could use JavaScript to replace the question name with "Game Over":

```
function timer001() {
  c = c - 1;
  if (c < 20) {
      time001.innerHTML = c;
  }
 
  if (c < 1) 
  {
    window.clearInterval(update);
    let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("btn")

    for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) 
    {
       buttons[i].disabled = true
    }

    // this line below will replace the question with "Game Over!"
    document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = "Game Over!"
  }
}
```

Comment: how do I restart the game, my function is not working. 
html
 <button id="restart-btn" class="restart-btn btn hide">Next</button>

scirpt
const restartButton = document.getElementById('restart-btn')

restartButton.addEventListener('click', restart)
function restart() {
    startGame();
    setNextQuestion();
    resetState();
}

Comment: could you please update your post with the full code?